# Unable to run node application along side of php

Tags: php, node.js, apache, lets-encrypt

I'm facing two basic problem which i'm unable to rectify

1) I've a subdomain(with virtual host) with `https` enabled via letsencrypt, now that subdomain works great with ssl when i visit `sub.domain.com` and browser shows green sign

Now when i type `sub.domain.com:8080` it serves my node application but as soon as i change it to `https://` browser say `unable to connect` which is beyond my imagination how this happening.

2) When first method didn't work, I jumped to second method, on my root domain `domain.com` inside `html` folder i placed node application with url like `domain.com/nodeapp` now when i visit this url, it shows folder structurer with various files and folder, now as soon as i turn the port number on `domain.com/nodeapp:8080/` browser shows `404` **note** i'm already running a php application on my root domain so it might conflict with it, but how can I solve this, We have one module which has to be in node, and we are unable to find the perfect solution.

Comment: `HTTPS` defaults to port 443. Is it possible for you to listen on that port?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your php application is served by an Apache web server, right? It has an extension which does the https encryption, if it is configured correctly (what letsencrypt normally does).

Your Node.js application is configured to listen on port 8080, but doesn't handle encryption automatically. Also, Letsencrypt doesn't configure it (yet) for you.

Have a look at [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-ssltls-with-node-js/) how to configure encryption for Node.js by yourself.